# Looking up FieldRef and FieldDef metadata tokens via Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, metadata, field, cil

I'm working on a program that pre-compiles bytecode from .NET assemblies.  This program is itself a .NET program - so far I've been able to use reflection to extract all the needed information including the bytecode itself.  However, I've run into a problem implementing the translation for `ldfld`.

`ldfld` and similar instructions have a metadata token within their encoding which references a *FieldRef* or *FieldDef*.  I understand these are elements in metadata tables embedded in the assembly's PE file.  In the worst-case I do have enough information from ECMA-335 to open the PE file and look all this up myself, but that's a lot of work and is not consistent with other information which I do get through Reflection, so I would prefer to do this lookup via Reflection.

However, I can't seem to find any methods on `System.Reflection.Assembly` that look up a metadata token.  (I may have just missed it.)  I can't do the lookup on anything more specific than an assembly because I only know the referencing assembly until I see the metadata (catch-22.)  In fact, as noted in the comments, I don't even know what assembly the field is *defined* in, until examining the metadata.

Is there any way to look up such metadata tokens via Reflection?

Comment: Go the other way around, Assembly.GetTypes => Type.GetFields => FieldInfo.MetadataToken.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for the tip.. looks like that should work.  Teaches me to go by the tree view in the left pane on MSDN... MetadataToken wasn't in there at all but I saw it in the resulting page if I clicked on the "Properties" heading.. not a very user-friendly site design!

Comment: @HansPassant .. however one possible problem I can think of (I'm still looking into) is that if the defining object is in a different assembly, it can't be found this way because the token in the `ldfld` would be valid only in the _consuming_ assembly, as a FieldRef therein, not in the assembly that defines the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't find anything on `Assembly`, because FieldDef and FieldRef don't belong to an assembly, they belong to a *module* (most assemblies have just a single module, but they can have more). And `Module` has exactly the method you want: [`ResolveField()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a8x293h.aspx). You would use it something like this:

```
Module module = …;
int fieldToken = …;
FieldInfo field = module.ResolveField(fieldToken);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed exactly what I was looking for.  I should have thought to check `Module` but I'm so used to 1:1 between executables and Assemblies.